# crontab not working fine?

Tags: cron

i have this crontab,

```
* * * * * php /etc/raddb/overloaded.php
```

but it is not running fine, meaning it doesnt run every minute, but when i manually enter this into the terminal (php /etc/raddb/overloaded.php), the script works

thank you guys

PS: im using centos 32 bit. also im using the "crontab -e" to insert and save crontab, but it looks like that crontab is not running? i typed "crontab -e" and yet (* * * * * php /etc/raddb/overloaded.php) appears. where is the issue here? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crontab syntax is right. Please check if your cron daemon is running and you can check log, maybe it conatins some usefull info.
I think the most possible problem is that cron has its own environment settings. Try to run php with its full path, e.g.

```
/sbin/php
```

or w\e path you have

Comment: how can i check if cron daemon is running

Comment: tnx! i did service crond start